# How can I add python type annotations to the flask global context g?

Tags: python, flask, mypy, python-typing, pyright

I have a decorator which adds a user onto the flask global context g:

```py
class User:
    def __init__(self, user_data) -> None:
        self.username: str = user_data["username"]
        self.email: str = user_data["email"]

def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        user_data = get_user_data()
        user = User(user_data)
        g.user = User(user_data)

        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrap
```

I want the type (User) of g.user to be known when I access g.user in the controllers. How can I achieve this? (I am using pyright)

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar issue described in [Typechecking dynamically added attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61213745/2650249). One solution is to add the custom type hints using [`typing.TYPE_CHECKING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING):

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from flask.ctx import _AppCtxGlobals

    class MyGlobals(_AppCtxGlobals):
        user: 'User'

    g = MyGlobals()
else:
    from flask import g
```

Now e.g.

```
reveal_type(g.user)
```

will emit

```
note: Revealed type is 'myapp.User'
```

If the custom types should be reused in multiple modules, you can introduce a partial stub for `flask`. The location of the stubs is dependent on the type checker, e.g. `mypy` reads custom stubs from the `MYPY_PATH` environment variable, `pyright` looks for a `typings` directory in the project root dir etc. Example of a partial stub:

```
# _typeshed/flask/__init__.pyi

from typing import Any
from flask.ctx import _AppCtxGlobals
from models import User


def __getattr__(name: str) -> Any: ...  # incomplete


class MyGlobals(_AppCtxGlobals):
    user: User
    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> Any: ...  # incomplete


g: MyGlobals
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution with an opinion:
`flask.g` is magic and is tied really hard to the server implementation. IMO, its usage should be kept contained and minimal.

I have created a file to manage g, which allowed me to type it

```py
    # request_context.py
    from flask import g
    from somewhere import User
    
    def set_user(user: User) -> None:
       g.user = user
    
    def get_user() -> User:
       # you could validate here that the user exists
       return g.user
```

and then in your code:

```py
    # yourcode.py
    import request_context
    
    class User:
        ...
    
    def login_required(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            user_data = get_user_data()
            user = User(user_data)
            request_context.set_user(User(user_data))
    
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    
        return wrap
```

Answer (score 3):

You could proxy the `g` object. Consider the following implementation:

```py
import flask


class User:
    ...


class _g:

    user: User
    # Add type hints for other attributes
    # ...

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return getattr(flask.g, key)


g = _g()
```

Comment: Very simple implementation that does everything I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You can annotate an attribute on a class, even if that class isn't yours, simply with a colon after it. For example:

```py
g.user: User
```

That's it. Since it's presumably valid everywhere, I would put it at the top of your code:

```py
from functools import wraps

from flask import Flask, g

app = Flask(__name__)


class User:
    def __init__(self, user_data) -> None:
        self.username: str = user_data["username"]
        self.email: str = user_data["email"]


# Annotate the g.user attribute
g.user: User


def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        g.user = User({'username': 'wile-e-coyote',
                       'email': 'coyote@localhost'})

        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrap


@app.route('/')
@login_required
def hello_world():
    return f'Hello, {g.user.email}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

That's it.

Comment: When I do this I get the following mypy error: Type cannot be declared in assignment to non-self attribute

Comment: Given that mypy is stated to be the reference implementation, I think it's pretty important that the answer works with mypy. If this isn't supposed to happen then I guess it's a bug in mypy which should be reported to mypy.

Comment: It is really unfortunate that this does not work with mypy. PyCharm does not recognize this construct either. @Ken Kinder, how did you get this to work? What IDE are you using?