# Polars API registering and type checkers

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, python-polars, pyright

I'm consistently getting type errors from either mypy or pyright when using polars namespace registration functions. Is there a way I can avoid type-checker errors other than hinting `# type: ignore[attr-defined]` every time I'm using a function from my custom namespace?

Example follows from the official documentation https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api.html :

file `checker.py`:

```
import polars as pl

@pl.api.register_expr_namespace("greetings")
class Greetings:
    def __init__(self, expr: pl.Expr):
        self._expr = expr

    def hello(self) -> pl.Expr:
        return (pl.lit("Hello ") + self._expr).alias("hi there")

    def goodbye(self) -> pl.Expr:
        return (pl.lit("Sayōnara ") + self._expr).alias("bye")


print(pl.DataFrame(data=["world", "world!", "world!!"]).select(
    [
        pl.all().greetings.hello(), # type: ignore[attr-defined]
        pl.all().greetings.goodbye(),
    ]
))
```

```
% mypy checker.py
checker.py:19: error: "Expr" has no attribute "greetings"  [attr-defined]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file
% mypy --version
mypy 1.8.0 (compiled: yes)
```

```
% pyright checker.py
/path/to/checker.py
  /apth/to/checker.py:19:18 - error: Cannot access member "greetings" for type "Expr"
    Member "greetings" is unknown (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
1 error, 0 warnings, 0 informations
% pyright --version
pyright 1.1.343
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polars API registration is non-compliant with Python's typing system. First and foremost, Polars can help by providing a dynamic attribute access typing hint. Without them doing this, only type-checkers with modding or plugin support can allow you to get around this.

#### Polars classes with dynamically-registerable namespaces need to define `__getattr__`

Type checkers (both mypy and Pyright) require error suppression because [`polars.expr.expr.Expr`](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/600d4f10ecd06cf6b20a052065e955374306577f/py-polars/polars/expr/expr.py#L109) does not have the dynamic attribute accessor defined. The presence of something like this:

```py
class Expr:
    if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
        def __getattr__(self, attr_name: str, /) -> typing.Any: ...
```

is sufficient to silence type checkers about dynamic attribute access (see [mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=75cd1cd9be95549b2d274aeef94a6d8e), [Pyright Playground](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=MYGwhgzhAECCBcAoaLoBMCmAzaB9XA5hgC5jHEBO%2BAFBBiFgDTRmW4B2YAthvNBJWYB6AJTQAtAD5oAewBGAKwzBifAHQbEiUJBgAhdZsRg%2BsaAF441EcbWQ0WBQGsQiOXz0Xoe627sQHZ1cgA), also [typing documentation >> Type System Reference >> Type Stubs >> Attribute Access](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/stubs.html?#attribute-access) - this equally applies to inline types in source files, such as Polars' `.py` files). I would suggest filing an issue with the Polars devs to ask them to add a dynamic `__getattr__` for typing purposes only.

#### Pyright requires per-file or per-line controls

For Pyright, these errors can't be suppressed except using a per-line `# type: ignore`s, or bunch of [file-level type controls](https://microsoft.github.io/pyright/#/comments?id=file-level-type-controls) like [`# pyright: reportUnknownMemberType=none, reportGeneralTypeIssues=none`](https://microsoft.github.io/pyright/#/configuration?id=type-check-diagnostics-settings). Pyright's BDFL has [previously expressed reluctance for plugin support](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/607#issuecomment-873467941), so it is unmoddable until someone writes a [Typing PEP](https://peps.python.org/topic/typing/) to propose a standard for somehow dynamically registering namespaces.

#### mypy can offer a statically-typed solution in the form of a [mypy plugin](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending_mypy.html)

It'd be great if Polars supported dynamic namespace registration, at least in  mypy, through a mypy plugin - I suggest pushing for this. You can use the following as an inspiration, which provides full static type checking of the registered namespaces.

##### mypy static type checking result

This is the kind of result you'd want to get:

```py
import polars as pl

@pl.api.register_expr_namespace("greetings")
class Greetings:
    def __init__(self, expr: pl.Expr):
        self._expr = expr

    def hello(self) -> pl.Expr:
        return (pl.lit("Hello ") + self._expr).alias("hi there")

    def goodbye(self) -> pl.Expr:
        return (pl.lit("Sayōnara ") + self._expr).alias("bye")
```

```
>>> print(
...     pl.DataFrame(data=["world", "world!", "world!!"]).select(
...         [
...             pl.all().greetings.hello(),
...             pl.all().greetings.goodbye(1),  # mypy: Too many arguments for "goodbye" of "Greetings"  [call-arg]
...             pl.all().asdfjkl                # mypy: `polars.expr.expr.Expr` object has no attribute `asdfjkl`  [misc]
...         ]
...     )
... )
...
```

##### Project structure

```
project/
  mypy.ini
  mypy_polars_plugin.py
  test.py
```

##### Implementation

Contents of `mypy.ini`

```
[mypy]
plugins = mypy_polars_plugin.py
```

Contents of `mypy_polars_plugin.py`

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing_extensions as t

import mypy.nodes
import mypy.plugin
import mypy.plugins.common

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import collections.abc as cx

    import mypy.options
    import mypy.types

STR___GETATTR___NAME: t.Final = "__getattr__"
STR_POLARS_EXPR_MODULE_NAME: t.Final = "polars.expr.expr"
STR_POLARS_EXPR_FULLNAME: t.Final = f"{STR_POLARS_EXPR_MODULE_NAME}.Expr"
STR_POLARS_EXPR_REGISTER_EXPR_NAMESPACE_FULLNAME: t.Final = "polars.api.register_expr_namespace"

def plugin(version: str) -> type[PolarsPlugin]:
    return PolarsPlugin

class PolarsPlugin(mypy.plugin.Plugin):

    _polars_expr_namespace_name_to_type_dict: dict[str, mypy.types.Type]

    def __init__(self, options: mypy.options.Options) -> None:
        super().__init__(options)
        self._polars_expr_namespace_name_to_type_dict = {}

    @t.override
    def get_customize_class_mro_hook(
        self, fullname: str
    ) -> cx.Callable[[mypy.plugin.ClassDefContext], None] | None:
        """
        mypy requires the presence of `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` for
        `get_attribute_hook` to work on dynamic attributes. This hook-getter adds
        `__getattr__` to the class definition of `polars.expr.expr.Expr`.
        """

        if fullname == STR_POLARS_EXPR_FULLNAME:
            return add_getattr
        return None

    @t.override
    def get_class_decorator_hook_2(
        self, fullname: str
    ) -> cx.Callable[[mypy.plugin.ClassDefContext], bool] | None:
        """
        Makes mypy recognise the class decorator factory
        `@polars.api.register_expr_namespace(...)` in the following context:

            @polars.api.register_expr_namespace(<namespace name>)
            class <Namespace>: ...

        Accumulates a mapping of a bunch of potential attributes to be accessible on
        instances of `polars.expr.expr.Expr`; the mapping has entries which look like
            `<namespace name>: <Namespace>`
        """

        if fullname == STR_POLARS_EXPR_REGISTER_EXPR_NAMESPACE_FULLNAME:
            return self.polars_expr_namespace_registering_hook
        return None

    @t.override
    def get_attribute_hook(
        self, fullname: str
    ) -> cx.Callable[[mypy.plugin.AttributeContext], mypy.types.Type] | None:
        """
        Makes mypy understand that, whenever an attribute is accessed from instances of
        `polars.expr.expr.Expr` and the attribute doesn't exist, reach for the
        attributes accumulated in the mapping through the actions of
        `get_class_decorator_hook_2`.
        """

        if fullname.startswith(f"{STR_POLARS_EXPR_FULLNAME}."):
            return self.polars_expr_attribute_hook
        return None

    def polars_expr_namespace_registering_hook(
        self, ctx: mypy.plugin.ClassDefContext
    ) -> bool:
        """
        Use the decorator factory `polars.api.register_expr_namespace(<namespace name>)`
        to register available dynamic attributes later accessed from instances of
        `polars.expr.expr.Expr`. Returns whether the class has enough information to be
        considered semantically analysed.
        """

        # Ensure that the class decorator expression looks like
        # `@polars.api.register_expr_namespace(<namespace name>)`
        namespace_arg: str | None
        if (
            (not isinstance(ctx.reason, mypy.nodes.CallExpr))
            or (len(ctx.reason.args) != 1)
            or (
                (namespace_arg := ctx.api.parse_str_literal(ctx.reason.args[0])) is None
            )
        ):
            # If the decorator factory expression doesn't look valid, do an early
            # return.
            return True

        self._polars_expr_namespace_name_to_type_dict[
            namespace_arg
        ] = ctx.api.named_type(ctx.cls.fullname)

        return True

    def polars_expr_attribute_hook(
        self, ctx: mypy.plugin.AttributeContext
    ) -> mypy.types.Type:
        """
        Reaches for registered namespaces when accessing attributes on instances of
        `polars.expr.expr.Expr`. Shows an error when the attribute doesn't exist.
        """

        assert isinstance(ctx.context, mypy.nodes.MemberExpr)
        attr_name: str = ctx.context.name
        namespace_type: mypy.types.Type | None = (
            self._polars_expr_namespace_name_to_type_dict.get(attr_name)
        )
        if namespace_type is not None:
            return namespace_type
        else:
            ctx.api.fail(
                f"`{STR_POLARS_EXPR_FULLNAME}` object has no attribute `{attr_name}`",
                ctx.context,
            )
            return mypy.types.AnyType(mypy.types.TypeOfAny.from_error)


def add_getattr(ctx: mypy.plugin.ClassDefContext) -> None:

    mypy.plugins.common.add_method_to_class(
        ctx.api,
        cls=ctx.cls,
        name=STR___GETATTR___NAME,
        args=[
            mypy.nodes.Argument(
                variable=mypy.nodes.Var(
                    name="attr_name", type=ctx.api.named_type("builtins.str")
                ),
                type_annotation=ctx.api.named_type("builtins.str"),
                initializer=None,
                kind=mypy.nodes.ArgKind.ARG_POS,
                pos_only=True,
            )
        ],
        return_type=mypy.types.AnyType(mypy.types.TypeOfAny.implementation_artifact),
        self_type=ctx.api.named_type(STR_POLARS_EXPR_FULLNAME),
    )
```

Contents of `test.py`

```py
import polars as pl


@pl.api.register_expr_namespace("greetings")
class Greetings:
    def __init__(self, expr: pl.Expr):
        self._expr = expr

    def hello(self) -> pl.Expr:
        return (pl.lit("Hello ") + self._expr).alias("hi there")

    def goodbye(self) -> pl.Expr:
        return (pl.lit("Sayōnara ") + self._expr).alias("bye")


print(
    pl.DataFrame(data=["world", "world!", "world!!"]).select(
        [
            pl.all().greetings.hello(),
            pl.all().greetings.goodbye(1),  # mypy: Too many arguments for "goodbye" of "Greetings"  [call-arg]
            pl.all().asdfjkl                # mypy: `polars.expr.expr.Expr` object has no attribute `asdfjkl`
        ]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

### You should use the `# type: ignore[attr-defined]` suppression.

Static typecheckers like `mypy` and `pyright` don't tend to do well with dynamic creation of attributes. If there's a lot of errors to suppress, you can add a comment near the top of the file to suppress this specific check for the entire file.

Here's how to do it for `mypy`:

```py
# mypy: disable-error-code="attr-defined"
import polars as pl
...
```

and here's how to do it for `pyright`:

```py
# pyright: reportGeneralTypeIssues=false
import polars as pl
...
```

Normally, the way to handle this is by adding type hints for custom `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` dunder methods (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61213745/17769815) question for more details). However, since this change would require modifying Polars code, the best solution is to simply suppress the errors.