# Type-checking dynamic attribute creation using Mypy plugins

Tags: mypy, python-typing

I have a codebase that uses a deeply weird pattern for defining command-line options. It looks like this:

```py
# opts.py

def group():
    o = OptionsGroup()
    return o, o.define

options = _SomeOptionsSingletonClass()

def define(name: str, type_: Type, default: bool, ...):
    # Create and set attribute on `options` singleton object to track this option.
    ...

class OptionsGroup:
    def define(name: str, type_: Type, default: bool, ...):
        define(*args)
```

Then, in various files across the codebase, either Pattern 1

```py
# some_module.py
from opts import group

options, define = group()

define("foo", type="str", ...)

# ...

print(options.foo) # How the heck do I typecheck this?
```

or Pattern 2:

```py
# some_module.py
from opts import options, define

define("foo", type="str", ...)

# ...

print(options.foo) # How the heck do I typecheck this?
```

We use `mypy` extensively to type-check code, and many of these options constructions are in critical paths that need coverage.

### Potential Solutions

- I cannot delete or refactor this pattern. It is deeply embedded in a large, production codebase.
- I am not aware of way to shoehorn this construction into the Python static typing system.
- The current solution is a very fragile script that attempts to parse these structures and rewrite them into a checkable type before executing `mypy`. I dislike this solution because it means `mypy` can't run against the *actual* codebase, and because the script's logic is very fragile. (I could fix the fragility).
- I've explored using a `mypy` plugin to infer and add types to the `options` value.

  - What I've found is that I cannot get the `get_function_signature_hook()` or `get_function_hook()` or `get_method_signature_hook()` or `get_method_hook()` hooks to fire on any of the calls to `define()` in Pattern 1.
  - I cannot easily use the Analyze Type hook because the classes involved don't implement `__getattr__()`, and changing the structure of these classes is pretty risky.

I would strongly prefer to use a `mypy` plugin or other strategy that allows typechecking to understand these structures in my actual source files, rather than a munged source tree.

### My Question

Broadly: is there a better solution to typecheck this pattern?

Narrowly: Is there any way I can get `mypy` to call my plugin while evaluating calls to `define()` and/or references to `options` attributes, so that I can synthesize types for these attribute references?

Comment: Ok, so there are several issues here: (1) I have a gut feeling that the mypy plugin won't work if you don't put type annotations on `group`, as in your example. (2) The `__getattr__` doesn't have to exist at runtime, you can add it under `TYPE_CHECKING` or add a fake one using the mypy plugin [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77733446/polars-api-registering-and-type-checkers/77771132#77771132). (3) Having `define` modify `options` without a clear link between the two seems very fragile, can you guarantee that `define` is called in the same module and scope as `options`?

Comment: Thanks for these thoughts, @dROOOze. (1) Apologies, the example is bad. `group()` does have type annotations. (2) This is a really interesting option. I'm going to experiment with an implementation using that strategy. (3) Yes, it's fragile. Unfortunately, I cannot get rid of this pattern - it's scattered throughout a very large, mature codebase.

Comment: I'm struggling a bit with some of your example - it raises a few questions. Lots of opts.py currently doesn't typecheck for me - what is `type_`? It's specified as a `type` but used as a `str`. I'm guessing *args just means all the attributes parsed into this. Can you add some more to "define" to show how these attributes are used? I'm also guessing name ends up being the name of an attribute in options based on usage but having the details of the function would be helpful. It's possible there's a way to resolve it but difficult to determine without more detail

Comment: Also am I correct in thinking you can change opts.py but not pattern1 or pattern2? I have a solution but it would be a wrapper around define

Answer (score 0):

So the below solution does involve changing the patterns slightly, but would be fully compatible with define, as it provides a wrapper around it. Hope this is useful to you!

We define a single class object, and this is then used for both type checking and for defining the variables. You could just update the pattern as and when you need to, as it shouldn't clash with what's happening in define (If define uses strings for type you might need to define a mapping in define_all). I've described it below for pattern 2 as it's simpler but there's no reason there couldn't be an equivalent for pattern 1:

```py
from typing import cast

# opts.py
class _SomeOptionsSingletonClass:
    pass

options = _SomeOptionsSingletonClass()

def define(name: str, type_: type):
    # Just made this up as an example use
    print(f"defined attr, {name}, type {type_}")
    if type_ == str:
        setattr(options, name, "test")
    elif type_ == int:
        setattr(options, name, 1)
    else:
        assert False

# New code for opts.py
class BaseTypesToAdd:
    pass

def define_all(t: type[BaseTypesToAdd]):
    for name, type_ in t.__annotations__.items():
        define(name=name, type_=type_)

# NewPattern2

class NewOptions(BaseTypesToAdd):
    foo: str
    bar: int

define_all(NewOptions)

options = cast(NewOptions, options)
print(options.foo)
```